# Merging two arraylists into one arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make program which merge two arraylists into one arraylist.

Problem is I can't use collections and should hard code it. I was able to do it until I got here. Could anyone try and help me please?

```
public static boolean isSorted(ArrayList<Integer> list)
{
    boolean sorted = true;        
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i-1).compareTo(list.get(i)) > 0) {
            sorted = false;
        }
    }
    return sorted;
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> merge(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {
    int num;
    boolean ASorted = isSorted(a);
    boolean BSorted = isSorted(b);
    ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    if(ASorted == false || BSorted == false) {
        return null;

    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++){
            c.add(b.get(i));
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++){
            num = a.get(j);
            if (num < c.get(j) ){
                c.add(j, num);
            } else if(j == 5|| num > c.get(j) ){
                c.add(j+2, num);
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
[1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6]
```

when using:

```
7 8 9 and 1 4 6
```

Comment: "Problem is i can't use collections" is little confusing since `ArrayList` is `Collection`. Do you mean you can't use `Collections` utility class?

Comment: *I can't use collections and should hard code it* you mean you cannot use `List#addAll`, right? Does this also mean that you cannot use `Iterator`?

Comment: i can use iterator but not lists or collection or addall @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: @Pshemo cant use lists, only ArrayList specifically.

Comment: But your parameters are `ArrayList` and this class implements `List`. This mean, you're using `List` inherently.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i know but these are my instructions.

Comment: I guess you should write your instructions in a clear way. And it's not that hard. Just check that both lists are not empty, traverse every element using an `Iterator` rather than this naive `for` loop or use enhanced `for` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will add two lists together to one list. You can apply any kind of logic here:

```
List<T> tList = new ArrayList<T>();
for (T element : listA) {
    tList.add(element);
}
for (T element : listB){
    tList.add(element);
}
```

If you need to use iterators, you can do this:

```
List<T> tList = new ArrayList<T>();
Iterator<T> fIt = listA.iterator();
while (fIt.hasNext()){
    tList.add(fIt.next());
}
Iterator<T> fIt2 = listB.iterator();
while (fIt2.hasNext()){
    tList.add(fIt2.next());
}
```

Comment: I cant use List, instructions from my professor. I need to hard code it using loops and iterator

Comment: @abdulaziz uh... just change `List` by `ArrayList`. Also, since you use `ArrayList` you're already using `List`. It's you who doesn't know how to explain your problem or your professor is not clear about the exercise. And this code uses iterator and and loop at the same time by using enhanced for loop.

Comment: Guys im completely stricted to arraylists only and the methods are as follow : add, remove, set, contains and clears

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your merging method is meant to also preserve order in returned `result` list, your solution should look like

```
while both lists have elements 
  pick top elements from lists say aInt, bInt
  compare them 
    place smaller one in result array
    move to next element in list which element was placed in result
when only one list will remain with elements
  place them in result
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you prof wants, change your code as you wish. You didn't mention sort so I didn't worry about it. I must tell you though, this is no where close to real standards (on job), so isn't the assignment. Hope it helps you for now.

```
package dummy;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DummyList {

    final static ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    final static ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    private static ArrayList<Integer> merge(ArrayList<Integer> l1, ArrayList<Integer> l2) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (Integer integer : l1) {
            list.add(integer);
        }

        for (Integer integer : l2) {
            if(!list.contains(integer))
                list.add(integer);
        }

        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list1.add(1);
        list1.add(3);
        list1.add(6);

        list2.add(2);
        list2.add(4);
        list2.add(6);

        ArrayList<Integer> mergedList = merge(list1, list2);
        System.out.println(mergedList);
        //sort here if needed.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer your way replace your 'j' loop by following:

```
for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++) {
    num = a.get(j);
    for (int k = 0; k < c.size(); k++) {
        if (num <= c.get(k)) {
            c.add(k, num);
            break;
        } else if (k + 1 == c.size()) {
            c.add(k + 1, num);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You have to add additional loop 'k' for output list.
You can compare this with logic which I prefer:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> merge3(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b)
{
    if (!isSorted(a) || !isSorted(b))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int ai = 0, bi = 0; ai < a.size() || bi < b.size();)
        {
            if (bi == b.size() || (ai < a.size() && a.get(ai) <= b.get(bi)))
            {
                c.add(a.get(ai++));
            }
            else if (ai == a.size() || (bi < b.size() && b.get(bi) <= a.get(ai)))
            {
                c.add(b.get(bi++));
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

It's the same logic like proposed by Pshemo